# Invoke Apex Action to send email from Screen Flow to multiple recepients

Tags: apex, flow-screen-component, flowscreen

Trying to invoke apex action to send email to multiple recipients through screenflow but still getting error : Error element SendEmail (FlowActionCall).
too many additional emails - max 5
The Apex action doesnt have any recepient metadata field

```
public class SendEmailToCasting {
    public static List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> sentEmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        public class EmailInputs {
        @InvocableVariable
        public List<List<String>> emailAddressesList;
        @InvocableVariable
        public String emailSubjectTemplate;
        @InvocableVariable
        public String emailTemplateContent;
    }

    @InvocableMethod(label='Send Email To Casting' callout='false')
    public static void SendEmailToCastingUsingFlowTemplate(List<EmailInputs> emailInputsList) {
        for (EmailInputs emailInputs : emailInputsList) {
            List<List<String>> emailAddressesList = emailInputs.emailAddressesList;
            String emailSubjectTemplate = emailInputs.emailSubjectTemplate;
            String emailTemplateContent = emailInputs.emailTemplateContent;

            for (List<String> emailList : emailAddressesList) {
                for (String emailAddress : emailList) {
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    String emailSubject = emailSubjectTemplate.replace('{!Notifications_Final_List.Craft_Name__c}', 'Craft Name');
                    emailSubject = emailSubject.replace('{!Current_Opportunity_Record_details.Name}', 'Opportunity Name');
                    mail.setSubject(emailSubject);
                    mail.setHtmlBody(emailTemplateContent);
                    mail.setToAddresses(new List<String>{emailAddress});

                    // Add the email to the list of sent emails
                    addToSentEmails(mail);

                    // Send the email
                    try {
                        Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{mail});
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.debug('Error sending email: ' + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Helper method to add emails to the list of sent emails
    public static void addToSentEmails(Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail) {
        sentEmails.add(mail);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  The error references a `SendEmail` element - do you still have a Send Email action in the flow in addition to your Apex action?